# OpenLayers 2 increase timeout for WPS call

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, javascript, wps

I am calling a WPS process with OpenLayers 2 (I know it is deprecated). I use the function `OpenLayers.Request.POST` and post an XML file. This works fine for "normal" requests. But I also need to call a process which needs at least 10 minutes to complete. But after ~ 5 minutes it seems that the connection is getting dropped and the request fails.

How can I increase this time limit in my JavaScript? Is this even possible or does the browser needs to be reconfigured for this?

Comment: The OpenLayers code doesn't appear to set a timeout.  Configuring browser timeouts depends on the browser  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798707/browser-timeouts

Comment: Maybe true but somehow there needs to be a workaround. Because when I do the same WPS call in Geoserver's Request Builder it has no problems to keep the connection for 20+ minutes. But when I run my own JS code it terminates after 5 minutes. From that I can call that there is a definitly a method. Now I just need to know how to implement this into my code